# Moving Elements to a New Line on Browser Resize

Tags: html, css, css-float

I'm looking for a solution that will dynamically move elements depending on the size of the browser.

Example:

I will use "X" as example of an element

If one user is viewing on a resolution similar to a mac, they will see

X X X X X X - The maximum amount of LIs / DIVs

If the browser is resized to half the size, they will see

X X X - Half the amount of LIs / DIVs

What would be the best way of going about this to try and replicate? an working example is seen here : http://www.therugcompany.com/gb/collection.html

Thanks for Looking!

Comment: CSS has some properties as `min-width`, `min-height`, `max-width`, `max-height` may be useful.

Comment: the link does not work. I think you're looking for media queries in css? http://css-tricks.com/css-media-queries/

Comment: Responsive designing?

Comment: and what it has to do with `php`?

Comment: I think you wouldn't need "responsive" design for this (media queries) - just old-school CSS w/floated elements.

Comment: @itachi - I didn't know if it would require PHP, that's why I included..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If the LIs/DIVs are floated elements, they'll naturally fall down to the next line as the width of their container gets smaller.

W3Schools has a nice example of exactly what you are describing, here:
http://www.w3schools.com/css/tryit.asp?filename=trycss_float_elements

That's from the main CSS Float topic page, here:
http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_float.asp

Comment: brilliant, thank you - there were elements in the stylesheet that were affecting the way it worked but i've chopped those bits out now and it works great - thank you!

Comment: @brii Glad it worked for you! You may want to accept the answer so future people who view the question can easily see that it was 1) answered, and 2) what the working solution was :)